# Pythagoras.js:10 POST http://localhost:5000/api/pythagoras net::ERR_ABORTED 400 (BAD REQUEST)

Tags: python, reactjs, api, flask

I'm getting this error when i'm trying to run a react app with an flask api that resolves a pythagoras theorem.

Here is the React code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Pythagoras() {
    const [a, setA] = useState(0);
    const [b, setB] = useState(0);
    const [c, setC] = useState(0);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/api/pythagoras', {
            mode: 'no-cors',
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({a: a, b: b}),
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setC(data.c))
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    A:
                    <input type="number" value={a} onChange={e => setA(e.target.value)}/>
                </label>
                <label>
                    B:
                    <input type="number" value={b} onChange={e => setB(e.target.value)}/>
                </label>
                <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
            </form>
            <h2>C: {c}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Pythagoras;
```

And here is the py code:

```
`from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/pythagoras', methods=['POST'])
def pythagoras():
    data = request.get_json()
    a = data['a']
    b = data['b']
    c = (a**2 + b**2)**0.5
    return jsonify({'c': c})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Any solution to this?

I tried using the flask-cors packages but it didn't work

Comment: Please provide the error so others can better understand the problem

Answer (score 1):

## Cause

The reason why you are getting this error is due to the 'no-cors' you've specified as your mode. You should remove this mode altogether or you could try again with 'flask-cors':

### Flask Cors Retry

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS # Import Package

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app) # Added this Line

@app.route('/api/pythagoras', methods=['POST'])
def pythagoras():
    data = request.get_json()
    a = data['a']
    b = data['b']
    c = (a**2 + b**2)**0.5
    return jsonify({'c': c})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**However** If that doesn't work for you, you could go an entirely different direction and mess around with proxies in react.

If you chose to go down this route you would have to go inside your **package.json** file located in the projects root directory and add **proxy** in the configuration. It should look a little something like this for you:

```
//package.json
{
  "name": "website",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
}
```

with this added to your package.json file you can fetch to "/api/pythagoras"

### **New Example with proxies set up:**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function Pythagoras() {
    const [a, setA] = useState(0);
    const [b, setB] = useState(0);
    const [c, setC] = useState(0);

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        // Changed Route & Removed 'no-cors'
        fetch('/api/pythagoras', { 
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({a: a, b: b}),
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setC(data.c))
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                    A:
                    <input type="number" value={a} onChange={e => setA(e.target.value)}/>
                </label>
                <label>
                    B:
                    <input type="number" value={b} onChange={e => setB(e.target.value)}/>
                </label>
                <button type="submit">Calculate</button>
            </form>
            <h2>C: {c}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Pythagoras;
```

Keep in mind though that the proxies set up in react will only work in development. In production, you would need to use something like [NGINX](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/) in order to forward all requests with "/api" to your flask application.

To use nginx and react together is a bit to get used to if you've never used nginx before, but there are a plethora of guides to help you along the way if you ever get lost.

If you need more clarification on any of the tips above then ask away.